Should all methods in Java interfaces have fallback defaults?
If I produce an interface with 3 methods, a, b, c then all classes implementing the interface are required to add a method body for them. This is fine as long as I work within a single project. When I publish my library though, I loose control over how people use interfaces - if in future I am to add a method d to the interface, then all code written previously will fail as existing classes didn't implement it. This could be overcome by upgrading those libraries but if they are published by 3rd party people, this is not possible (unless open source) which makes the whole process fail.
The solution could be

to create an additional interface if a new method is added,
or to add a method with a blank implementation that simply returns null/void so that older code is still compatible.

New interfaces are fine but then this implies that no new features can actually include new methods in an interface which is not ideal.
Did you come across this issue before and have you decided to use the default blank implementation approach?

"blank implementation" is a poor choice of terms. Reword to be more clear.

"which makes the whole process fail" it will happens anyway, because for default to work you need recompile code that implements interface.

Read up on semantic versioning, it's related to your problem.

@talexmovedtoCodidact As far as I'm aware, that is not necessary.

This is pretty clear-cut: In many cases (probably most cases) you cannot provide any meaningful default implementation, so just don‘t. Publishing an interface with methods a(), b()  and c() without default implementations is fine. When you later extend it with d(), giving a default implementation for d() will solve the problem you mention, so you should if you meaningfully can (and if not, consider not adding d()).,

or to add a method with a blank implementation that simply returns null/void A bad idea in the vast majority of cases. It‘s sure to lead to bugs. Fortunately I have only seen it done in very few cases where an implementation that did nothing was expected to be appropriate for the majority of use cases.

The standard set by the JDK is to add default implementations to new functions, and if no sensible default implementation is possible, you don't get to add the method at all.

default implementation on interface
You said:

if in future I am to add a method d to the interface, then all code written previously will fail as existing classes didn't implement it.
solution could be … to add … implementation

Allowing a default implementation on an interface in Java was invented to solve precisely your issue.
When adding lambdas, the Java team needed to add new method signatures to the interfaces in the Java Collections Framework. Adding new method signatures to an interface could be supported by implementing the new methods on the bundled classes, they faced the problem where outside the JDK/JRE, other parties had written classes implementing those interfaces. As you noted, newly-added unimplemented methods appearing suddenly would break compatibility. By inventing default implementations to be placed within the interface, problem solved. Old classes would automagically fall-back to the default method implementation where needed.
Generally, default implementations on interfaces in Java are discouraged. But your case is exactly the situation for which they were invented.
For more info, see JEP 126: Lambda Expressions & Virtual Extension Methods. The “virtual extension methods” are default implementations on an interface.
Technically the default implementation on an interface in Java is a form of what is more generally known as a Mixin.
If by "blank implementation" you mean a dummy method that does no real work, then No, you should not do this. Default methods only make sense where a reasonable useful fall-back method is feasible.
Multiple interfaces
You said:

solution could be …  create an additional interface

Yes, this can be a smart approach. Do this when your situation can be cleanly divided into groups of related behavior, where it makes sense that an implementation class might logically partake of one group of behaviors while declining another.
And remember that an interface can have sub-interfaces. You can add new interfaces that extend from an existing interface, a super-interface. A class implementing the super-interface is not obligated to implement the sub-interface. And, a class implementing the sub-interface would also implement the super-interface as well.

Thank you Basil, I appreciate your response, it was exactly what I wanted to hear from a Java expert with knowledge of historical background. also great point on super-interfaces, but i'm not sure that's always applicable because then i would have to change the arg to the new sub-interface and accepting a super-interface would no longer work - i'd have to extend the super-class with a sub-class, but because interfaces can be multiple, and extension is 1, this doesn't really work well. also i wouldn't call it 100% mixins/traits because default methods can't make use of fields which is limiting.


Should all methods in Java interfaces have fallback defaults?

I think the answer is plainly No.
While I can see a benefit in providing a default or fallback implementation in some cases (e.g. using default as per Basil's answer), it is not good practice to do this in all cases.
An advantage of an interface not having default implementation is that is forces the programmer to think about the problem.  Sometimes (maybe often) you don't need to think about, but sometimes you absolutely do need to.  This applies whether interface method was in the original version of the API, or whether it is being added.
The root problem is some methods simply don't have a good default implementation.  For example, suppose that we added a new interface method to return a unique identifier for the entity that some object represents.  A default method could refer to any of the fields of the object, so what could it do?

It could return a constant, but then multiple distinct entities would have the same identifier.  Incorrect.
It could call an id generator and return the result, but how would it remember the identifier it returned from the last call?  Incorrect.
It could throw a "not implemented yet" exception, but then we've just replaced a compile time problem with a runtime problem.  Incorrect.

In fact, I don't think there is a solution for this example.  We can't use a default method in this example ... and hence, we can't in all cases ... which is what you are proposing.

The lesson is that default methods (or similar) are a useful tool, but sometimes you have to accept that a change in an interface will require corresponding changes to classes.  Each case should be handled on its merits.

We're talking about 2 different things. The problem you're addressing is coding, while i'm taking about maintenance. Thank you for the provided points, but I'm not interested in philosophy regarding the semantics of the default method, I need to address the fact that interfaces provide contracts for people to fulfil in things like plugins / compiler passes that are developed externally and are included in the main system, and as the main system evolves, new features could be added - without a dummy return null default method implementation the plugins quickly become unnecessary incompatible.

You're right though regarding of "what the method should do" - it can't do anything significant, that's why I'm talking about a blank/dummy method that returns null / void which is clearly stated in the question. This however is not really correct because returning null could also have a meaning. I think the only solution is extend the interface and then perform if-branching based on instanceof against the new sub-interface or the old super-interface to keep things compatible.

You are describing the first bullet point, where null is the constant.  As noted, that is incorrect behavior per the "get unique id" spec ... 'cos it isn't a unique id.  Yes interface subclassing could solve this ... but there is no way that you can avoid modifying the classes that implement the (modified or subclass) interface.   That was the rationale for your fallback defaults idea.  Ergo, it doesn't work in all cases, and that was >my< point.

It would work with returning null if the null-behaviour was predefined as "unimplemented" and a check for null was made where the interface is used but that quickly becomes annoying to assume that a method could be unimplemented by some class. it's just i came across the visitor pattern and found a visitor interface then wanted to add a .visit{X} method to visit a new kind of node i added to the parser, but then all the existing visitor-classes in the system broke, so i'm thinking how i can add new backwards-compatible behaviour as the if-instanceof switch defeats the visitor purpose.
